# FOSUserBundle - perform function upon initial login

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I have a Symfony 3 application with user management via FOSUserBundle. I want to implement a Listener class that checks for an initial user login, by checking the user's "last_login" value. While I did read the [article on event subscribers](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html), I struggle to find out when exactly the last_login value is updated.
Is there anyone with such knowledge, or does anyone know a better approach regarding a user's initial login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a look at this and it seems you can use an eventSubscriber to subscribe to the SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN event to get where you need to be.

```
class RegistrationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
private $tokenStorage;

public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
} 
 public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => [
            ['lastLogin', 150],
        ],
    ];
}
public function lastLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event){
    $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    if($user->getLastLogin() == null){
     //Do something
    }
}
```

In my testing on the first login $user->getLastLogin() is null so you can put any logic you need here.

Comment: What exactly is the 150 for?

Comment: the 150 is the priority that i chose at random

Answer (score 1):

Symfony and FOSUserBundle have events for that. Even FOSUserBundle has an event subscriber for those events

```
/**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN => 'onImplicitLogin',
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onSecurityInteractiveLogin',
        );
    }
```

you could subscribe for those events and make your own logic. There is no such thibg as initial login in symfony, you need to manage by your self.

Subscribe to the events and try something like this:

```
public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event){

    $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
    //some logic to check the user
    if(!$user->getLastLogin()){
    //its my first login!!! do what ever you want here
    }else{
        //I have already logged before so just pass
    }
}
```

Also you need to change your subscriber priority to -10 or something like that to catch the event before FOSUserBundle or you will be passing always.

Hope it helps